# How can I create a stored procedure in MySql?

Tags: mysql, procedure

I'm trying to create a stored procedure but i have an error: "Statement is uncomplete, expecting ";"

```
    use kms;
    create procedure getAllClients()
    BEGIN
    select * from Clients;
    END;
```

Comment: This is not MySQL error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
use kms;
DELIMITER //
create procedure getAllClients()
BEGIN
    select * from Clients;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```